# Angular 2 router ngIf dynamic route

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-routing

How to **ngIf** dynamic **router** ? For example I have **top navigation component** which has back **button** and I want that back **button** would only be visible on `'item/:id'` route with:

`*ngIf="router.url == '/item' or '/item/:id'` - and it's not working.

**How to *ngIf dynamic routes ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could build route guards. The `canActivate` guard turns on a flag and the `canDeactivate` turns off the flag. The navigation item would then be bound to that flag.

Or you could add a routing even watcher that watches for specific events and turns on/off a flag that you can bind to.

In this example, I'm using routing events to turn on/off a flag to manage a spinner:

```
  constructor(private authService: AuthService,
              private router: Router,
              private messageService: MessageService) {
    router.events.subscribe((routerEvent: Event) => {
      this.checkRouterEvent(routerEvent);
    });
  }

  checkRouterEvent(routerEvent: Event): void {
    if (routerEvent instanceof NavigationStart) {
      this.loading = true;
    }

    if (routerEvent instanceof NavigationEnd ||
        routerEvent instanceof NavigationCancel ||
        routerEvent instanceof NavigationError) {
      this.loading = false;
    }
  }
```

You could do something similar watching for NavigationStart events for a particular set of routes. For example (not tried):

```
  constructor(private authService: AuthService,
              private router: Router,
              private messageService: MessageService) {
    router.events.subscribe((routerEvent: Event) => {
      this.checkRouterEvent(routerEvent, router.url);
    });
  }

  checkRouterEvent(routerEvent: Event, routerUrl: string): void {
    if (routerEvent instanceof NavigationStart && routerUrl == '/item') {
      this.myflag= true;
    }

    if (routerEvent instanceof NavigationEnd ||
        routerEvent instanceof NavigationCancel ||
        routerEvent instanceof NavigationError) {
      this.myflag= false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Could you please provide example ? Because I tryed a lot and can't achieve it.